# passwordless ssh from windows to linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, openssh

I have this ssh config

```
Host srv.example.com srv
  HostName srv.example.com
  User theo
  PasswordAuthentication no
  ServerAliveInterval 240
  ServerAliveCountMax 2
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I open the git console in mingw, I remove my old .ssh/id_rsa keys from both my pc and the remote, then I type

```
> ssh-keygen -t rsa
...
> ssh-copy-id -t ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub srv
(password prompt)
> ssh aiadm
theo@srv.example.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

Here is the verbose output

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\theo/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\theo/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for example
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "srv.example.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to srv.example.com [<IP>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\theo/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/theo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/theo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\theo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to srv.example.com:22 as 'theo'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\theo/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\theo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from srv.example.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/theo/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:648DfWWZeoOSAq3Ea83UA2GvS1kZCoGAoRz1LShMfRM
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\theo/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\theo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from srv.example.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/theo/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\theo/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\theo/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from <IP>
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/theo/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host 'srv.example.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\theo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\theo/.ssh/id_rsa (0000021C66B7D9A0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:ZJfeFlMoEpwtfIOxmINCHaJGYDcLIF9HosggeO3+RGE C:\\Users\\theo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
theo@srv.example.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: 1) Log into server (with password etc.) and veryify that `id_rsa.pub` appears in `~theo/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and that this file has the correct permissions. 2) Put `sshd` on the server in verbose mode, try again and see what the server complains about.

Comment: It exists along with my linux machine's key in which I can ssh but it is at work, I also can't manage anything on the remote host. can they disable passwordless ssh for a machine on the outside of work network?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your setup. What "linux machine's key"? Where is that stored? How is `ssh-copy-id` supposed to work, if you don't have a working password? To be able to distribute a newly generated key, you *have* to be able to login to the server somehow. If you "accidentally" deleted your old ssh key, you have a problem.

Comment: I am sorry if I confused you, I have a linux machine at work in which I can login without a password to srv.example.com. When I `cat authorized_keys` from srv.example.com I can see the two keys, one of the linux machine at my work and one of the windows machine I am trying to use. I have done the same steps from my work machine to do the passwordless ssh and it worked, but when I do the same on my windows machine it doesn't.

Comment: Your permissions on the files, that cannot be read are either incorrect or the files are missing.  Are those files missing?

Comment: The only thing I can see from the verbose output of the client is that the server at some stage refused to accept the key, and it started over. I'd still say run `sshd` on the server in verbose mode (with `-d`, or via `sshd_config`), then compare the output when you login from the linux machine at work, and your windows machine.  You need to be root on the server to do that (or you can ask the sysadmin of that server to do it).